# How to use Column Alias in Informix database table

Tags: informix

I want to use column aliases while selecting the column in an informix database table.
For example in the following query:

```
SELECT hire_dt as "Hire Date" FROM employee
```

Column hire_dt should be displayed as Hire Date. How can I do this in informix?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is fine as long as you have the `DELIMIDENT` environment variable set. Read up about it in the [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_14.1.0/com.ibm.sqlr.doc/ids_sqr_233.htm).

Comment: Be cautious about adding DELIMIDENT to an environment not used to it; queries that used to work can fail because programmers used double quotes around strings - but those become (case-sensitive) identifiers when DELIMIDENT is set.

Comment: Agreed, DELIMIDENT should be avoided at all costs, apart from anything it breaks replication amongst other things...

Comment: I have found this question because select using camelcased aliases that worked yesterday, did not worked in new tests. I had the DELIMIDENT in the connection string and all column names in IFX resultset metadata were lowercased.
Without DELIMIDENT set it works as expected.
I don't use double quotes in any SQL - causes many problems with invalid SQL.

Answer (score 1):

In you connection string you can use:

```
Database=mydatabase;Host=192.168.100.1;Max Pool Size=3;
Min Pool Size=1;Pooling=True;Protocol=onsoctcp;Password=informix;
Server=ol_server;Service=1256;User ID=informix;delimident=y
```

> delimident=y